# Use an output parameter of store procedure in update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a store procedure which insert data into a `table1` and there is another store procedure which insert data in `table2` I need to insert `table2.ID` in `table1` while updating I am calling second store procedure in first and it returns me the `Id` as an `output parameter` but it didn't get updated.

SP1 :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateSP]
@prm1 varchar(30),
@prm2 varchar(20),
@prm3 varchar(20),
@prm3 varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    DECLARE @ID int 
    exec SPInsert @ID OUTPUT, @prm1,  @prm2 , @prm3 
    update tbl1 set status = prm1, updated_by = prm2, updated_date = GETDATE(), reason_id = @ID  where student_no = prm3
END
```

SP2 :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPInsert]
@prm1 varchar(30),
@prm2 varchar(20),
@prm3 varchar(20),
@prm3 varchar(max),
@ID output,
AS
BEGIN
Insert into tbl2 (student_no, reason_txt, created_by, created_date)Values(@prm1 ,@prm2 ,@prm3 , GETDATE())
Select @ID = Scope_Identity()
END
```

Comment: `@ID int output` should be declared in `SPInsert` parameter list.

Comment: Your second procedure shouldn't even compile since `@ID` is never declared.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev it is a copy mistake

Comment: does `tbl2` have `identity` column?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev yes it does have it

Comment: if I exec SPInsert it give me the inserted Id but I am not able to figure out why in update statement it is getting in

Comment: @ Hi think your exec doesn’t have good paremeter order Exec SPInsert prm1, prm2, prm3, ID output

Comment: oh yes thanks @pascalsanchez got the issue